# Restoring a MySQL database to a failed master

Tags: mysql, replication, multi-master

I have a master-master configuration in MySQL with two servers. One server should stay live on the network to serve requests (call it server A) and the other should be taken offline to push new code changes (server B).

My idea originally was that after running STOP SLAVE on both servers, that server B could be shut down, updated, and even have a new database schema put in. After this, I thought that I could simply START SLAVE on server B and have the entire database from server A replicated/mirrored back over to server B. However, this is not the case. Restarting the slave and doing a CHANGE MASTER TO (...) and syncing up the log files does not replicate old changes like I want it to: it only replicates new writes from that point on.

I am looking for a way to bring server B up to speed with the latest database from server A, and then have server B continue to replicate changes in a master-master setup. Then I can continue the sequence of server upgrades by doing the same process but keeping server B online only.

Any solutions which require locking the tables will not work since I need to do this change without any downtime. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

**Slow ALTER in Master-Master**

In Master-Master, each server is acting both as a Master and a Slave to the other server.

`STOP SLAVE` -- When you later do `START SLAVE`, the stuff that was performed on the Master will be applied to the Slave.  If you did, say, a big `ALTER` on a big table, that `ALTER` will run, taking a long time.  This is probably the "downtime" you are worried about?

The alternative is to do the lengthy process twice.

1. Stop client usage of B.
2. On B, turn off writing to the binlog
3. On B, do the `ALTER(s)`, etc.
4. On B, turn on writing to the binlog
5. Wait for replication to catch up.  (It was probably blocked by the `ALTER`.)
6. Flip -- that is stop talking to A and start talking to B.
7. On A, (steps 2,3,4,5) binlog off, ALTER, binlog on, catch up

**Alternatives**

In Galera, this is "RSU" (as opposed to "TOI").

See also `pt-online-schema-change` -- this tool (percona.com) allows for doing time consuming maintenance on a table with essentially no downtime.

5.7 can now do *many* `ALTERs` with `ALGORITHM=INPLACE`, hence little or no downtime.

**Putting the burden on the Code**

Keep in mind that some *code* changes involve *schema* changes.  Sometimes they can be done in a "backward compatible" manner, thereby obviating stuff like this.

In the extreme, you might need to double up the *code*.  That is, have it capable of handing the old schema and the new schema *at the same time*.  This complicates the code, but eliminates coordination problems between code and schema.  (The code should eventually be cleaned up to throw out the 'old' variant.)

That last way becomes especially important when you have Sharding, multiple clients, or other cases of "lots of servers to update".

Comment: I am currently already doing that 7 step process. I think my question was more along the lines of, if server B has nothing (all tables are truncated) and server A holds all the data and it is being written to by clients, is there a way to 'mirror' over all the changes back to server B without taking server A offline.

Comment: Replication does _not_ provide an automatic transfer of data.  It _only_ transfers things that were just now inserted/updated/deleted.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the clarification. So what sort of tools/tactics do you suggest if the two masters become out of sync? Say a server gets shut down for an hour and is now missing entries and/or has entries which are old. How would you bring that server back up to speed with the live database? I guess that is closer to my question.

Comment: After re-establishing Master-Slave, replication should "catch up" and be in sync after that.  What Engine are you using?  What binlog format (ROW/MIXED/STATEMENT)?

Comment: Check the percona toolkit -- pt-table-checksum and pt-table-sync